# Open pop-up at remote pc in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

First , I explain you Flow .

I have UserX,who is online at X country and UserY,who is online at Y-country.

----------------

what i want :

When UserX click on ajax button.Popup is open at UserY's PC.

-----------------

Condition :

I dont want to set timeout  ajax request ,because of this,server become slow.

------------------

It is possible.

If you have any idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Comets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), here is some [example](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)