# How to pull new post and comments

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp-1.3

I am currently developing a website where many users post topics and the associated topics' comments are shown in the page. Currently I'm developing using cake php.

The very first time a user clicks the website, all the topics and comments are displayed. But when other users add new topic or comment to a  topic, I need to show the update in the same page. I am confused as in how am I able to retrieve new contents and update accordingly in a page. For instance how facebook does it where when your friends adds status or comments on your status, it updates without refreshing the page.

I know that AJAX technology is used but how is it done. Any source that I can refer?  Hope someone can help as I have been doing research for the past one week but no answers so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007160/open-pop-up-at-remote-pc-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go two routes in this.

**Server Push**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

This technique is perhaps the most efficient as the server notifies the client of any updates. However this technique usually requires a bit more work than a simple polling system. You can use something like [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) or [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to push updates. If you're using nodejs, I highly recommend using [SocketIO](http://socket.io/) to handle the client side. With Socket.io you can have the client side listening to the server on a channel so that the server can notify the client whenever an update happens.

**Client polls server**

In this version, the client (new visitors browser) constantly polls the server for updates. You can set whatever gap you want, but keep in mind that if you make the polling gap too small your server might take a performance hit as each new user will create many requests. This method is as simple as setting up a `setInterval()` call in JS coupled with an AJAX call.

Comment: The socketIO site has lots of examples for server push. And these are quite useful as well : http://www.screenr.com/SNH , http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/ Polling depends on how you make it work. But looking at this example might help : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/ That's for jquery

Comment: Thank you. I will try and soon mark answered :) You are very helpful! I hope to hear from others too :)

Comment: Server Push would not be possible as i am using windows system. However i am going with the second option: Client Polls Server. Hope i can achieve it ...

Comment: @madi: i face same pronlem . if u get solution then told me.

Comment: @chetan: I am headless to start. I don't even know where to start unless we collaborate.

Comment: This is a good place to get an idea : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/ That tutorial covers the concept using the jQuery framework as well as the MooTools framework. Get your PHP working first, then enhance with JS